# PHP: ignore errors and continue without try catch

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to avoid writing if else on every line,

This is my code example:

```
isset($arr['first_name']) ? $first = $arr['first_name'] : null;
isset($arr['last_name']) ? $last = $arr['last_name'] : null;
```

I want to be able to tell PHP to just ignore and continue if I try to do something like that:

```
$first = $arr['first_name'];
$last = $arr['last_name'];
```

I don't want to put the code inside of a try catch because it will not get to the last name part if the first name isn't there it will just go to the catch part and cancel all the code inside the try part,

I want to only have the $first or $second in case that the other isn't present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@` character to silence PHP.
Like this:

```
$first = @$arr['first_name'];
$last = @$arr['last_name'];
```

**NOTE**: This is bad coding. Avoid whenever you can.

Comment: Do you know of a "Good coding" solution?
What would you do in this case?
Just add a bunch of ifs?

Comment: $first = isset($arr['first_name']) ? $arr['first_name'] : null;

Comment: This is what I have right now, But I sometimes have a lot of lines which I'm trying to save some code here, and not end up with 20 lines just for that...

Comment: you asked for good coding :D good coding is checking your data before saveing it

Comment: I'm checking it, I'm working with Laravel and this code is inside of a service that saves the translation attributes of a model, before I get to the service I have a FormRequest validation that check all the fields, Only then I send the data to the service and because I have some models with 10+ optional translated attributes I need to check in the service for the existence of each value and I want to avoid writing validation again